# EditText very ugly with appcompat

Tags: android, android-appcompat

I recently updated appcompat and this caused EditText to look very bad on pre-Lollipop versions.

Here is the theme I use :

```
 <style name="Theme.Launcher" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:colorBackgroundCacheHint">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowShowWallpaper">true</item>
</style>
```

It doesnt look like Material Design EditText at all 
Please help me
Thanks

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/rengwuxian/MaterialEditText

Comment: can you define your "ugly" EditText .. some picture will do good

Comment: the EditText is the blue thing http://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2014/52/1419334931-screenshot-2014-12-23-12-41-46.png

Comment: There is no "blue thing" in that screenshot, other than a launcher icon and some status bar icons.

Comment: http://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2014/52/1419340747-sc.png